# Limit on PanGestureRecognizer Concurrently - Swift - Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I am displaying an array of movable cards (`UIViews`) in `viewController`.
This cards have each set a pan Gesture recogniser  that allows them to be moved.

When I move a card up `self.removeFromSuperview()` is called and the view is removed from the viewController's view.

The problem is that since I have displayed many cards one in top of the other, the first one I move around lags a lot and drops some frames.

After some views are removed tho, the user experience improves and It doesn't drop frames anymore.

I was wondering If there was a limit in how many panGestureRecongizers there may be concurrently.

To investigate more what was causing the issue, I tried to use the Time Profiler tool to see what may cause this traffic on the `main thread` and this is what I found out: [image: found out]

To be honest I'm pretty new to time profiler tool but what I think I see it's causing the problem is indeed the panGesturerecogniser method.

Is this possible or may I search on another path?